# Using AppDelegate method in ViewController

Tags: objective-c, xcode, webview, startup

NOTE: Problem Solved. Thanks

I'm simply a high school student on a brand new app developer program. So, please excuse me seeming like I know very little, as, I really don't know as much as I will yet. Bear with me XD

I need to use the following startup from AppDelegate to display a start screen for the webView in my application, rather than a blank white screen:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

// THIS SECTION IS WHAT I NEED
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.earlham.k12.ia.us"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:request];


return YES;
```

}

To use that, however, I need access to webView, which is my WebView object that I declared in ViewController.h. However, that doesn't work, because I can't declare it twice, nor use it from the other header file, to my knowledge. I know it's possible, but at this basic level, I don't know how. Please include code examples.

Many thanks!

Comment: Note to answerers: this is a homework question. To improve the general quality in the world of developers, only provide thoughts, not direct code that he can just copy/paste.

Comment: Final project and you don't know how to setup a view controller?

Comment: can you show us how the webView is declared in ViewController.h. In any case, you threat webView as a variable that belongs to the appDelegate which is probably not the case. If it belongs to viewController you will need to write something like [viewController.webView loadRequest:request] Additionally, you will need to add the view of the viewController to the viewStack of the application.

Comment: Listen, I do have permission to ask for help on this; Tom. Rephrasing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you put this in the application delegate? This looks like something the actual ViewController should be able to handle.

Comment: As a starting coder, I don't have the expertise to devise a way around it. I do know fluent Java, so I am not completely incompetent in coding, just Objective-C

Comment: So; I rephrase. Is there a way to set home page on startup from ViewController?

Comment: `-(void)viewDidLoad` in the UIViewController can do that for you. Simply create the method and add your code there.

Comment: Much appreciated. Thank you for your help, I'll try it and be back shortly

Comment: Amazingly enough, I had used that exact solution before! As a matter of fact, I had it in a developers note from when I first started, but it wasn't necessary then. I just took it out of the note and it works fine now. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

The instance of `UIWebView` should only be managed by its containing `UIViewController`. The app delegate is responsible for getting the view controller on screen as a subview of the window. From there, it is the view controllers responsibility to manage the web view appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the other answers that this code should belong in the view controller, not in the  app delegate.

If you do want to access code in your app delegate, you'll have to create a method containing the code you want and call that from your view controller (since you don't want to be calling didFinishLaunchingWithOptions yourself, it gets called for you at the right time).

In general though, it's better to separate out responsibility in your code and not put general code in your app delegate.